# adding blank legend in R leaflet package?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

Is there any way to add a 'blank' legend with just a title to a leaflet map using the R leaflet pacakge? I was hoping to mimic a map title using a blank legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `addControl()` argument to add a legend and pass an html paragraph `tags$p` i.e. a string of text (here in bold, `tags$b`)

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)

my_title <- tags$p(tags$style("p {color: red; font-size:22px}"),
            tags$b("My_beautiful_title_goes here"))


my_map <- leaflet() %>%
addTiles() %>%
setView(10.533, 45.822, zoom = 11) %>%
addControl(my_title, position = "bottomright" )

my_map
```

Comment: Awesome! This might be stretching my luck but any way to change the font size of the title?

Comment: I edited the answer. Change the number in `font-size:22px` to adjust the size of the text. Bonus: You can change the color as well :)